# Does anything exist that converts text files into string literals as a build step?

Tags: c, string, build, build-process

I have multiple text files, and I'd like them to be converted into source files containing string literals at build time.

For example, if `hello.txt` contains this text:

> Hello,
>
> This is a text file.

I'm looking for the output to be something like this:

```
const char* HELLO_TXT = "Hello,\n\nThis is a text file.";
```

Does anything like this already exist, or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: You could try `#include` in combination with the new c++11 [`R"txt()txt"`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) string literals. But I'm not sure if this is really good advice to do.

Comment: You can probably find any number of such programs floating around on the internet, many of them called `txt2c` or similar.

Comment: You need to create a script to do this (using Python, for example) and add a build phase for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a standard utility called xxd which will do exactly this (http://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd ).  Add it as as one of your build steps before compiling.  The -i option generates a hex dump of a file in "C include" format.  So with a hello.txt thta contains only the string "hello", the output of

```
xxd -i hello.txt > hello.h
```

would look something like:

```
char *hello_txt = { 0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f };
int hello_txt_len = 5;
```

You can then #include this file into your source code and access hello_txt to get the contents of your file.  Note that the array is not null terminated.